How to solve $\cos^3{(x)}+\cos{(3x)}-2\sin^3{(x)}=0$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$?
How to solve $\cos^3{(x)}+\cos{(3x)}-2\sin^3{(x)}=0$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$?
I tried writing $\cos{(3x)}$ as $4\cos^3{(x)}-3\cos{(x)}$; or $\sin^3{(x)}$ as $-\frac{1}{4} \sin{(3x)}+\frac{3}{4} \sin{(x)}$ to check to see if I could factor out anything, and then use that the product must be zero. But nothing worked. I do not have more ideas to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Like @user2661923 I would first get it into just $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, then I'd put $t=\tan (x/2)$ and you'll get a polynomial equation in $t$ of degree $6$. I don't think it has obvious solutions but I haven't worked it carefully.

$$\cos^3x+\cos3x-2\sin^3x=0 \iff5\cos^3x-2\sin^3x=3\cos x$$
Divide both sides by $\cos^3x$ and writing $\tan x=t$
$$5-2t^3=\dfrac3{1+t^2}\iff5+5t^2-2t^3-2t^5=3\iff2t^5+2t^3-5t^2+2=0$$

@labbhattacharjee. This is a good idea, for sure.

The trigonometric equation:
$$
\cos^3(x)+\cos(3x)-2\sin^3(x)=0
$$
is equivalent to:
$$
2\cos^3(x)-3\sin^2(x)\cos(x)-2\sin^3(x)=0
$$
which is certainly not verified for $x=\pm\pi$.
Therefore, we can set $t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, i.e. $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, from which:
$$
\underbrace{t^6-9t^4+8t^3+9t^2-1}_{p(t)}=0\,.
$$
So, once the six first-attempt solutions on the unit circle have been calculated:
$$
t_k = \cos(2\,k\,\pi/6) + i\sin(2\,k\,\pi/6)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; k = 1,2,\dots,6
$$
it's sufficient to update them about ten times by applying the Aberth-Ehrlich method:
$$
t_k' = t_k - \left(\frac{p'(t_k)}{p(t_k)} - \begin{aligned}\sum_{j=1;\,j\ne k}^6\end{aligned}\frac{1}{t_k-t_j}\right)^{-1}
$$
from which:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& t_1 = 1.94649 - 0.58785\,i\,; \\
& t_2 = -0.470804 - 0.142185\,i\,; \\
& t_3 = -0.470804 + 0.142185\,i\,; \\
& t_4 = 1.94649 + 0.58785\,i\,; \\
& t_5 = -3.25828 + 5.04871\cdot 10^{-29}\,i\,; \\
& t_6 = 0.30691 - 1.31722\cdot 10^{-40}\,i\,. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
In conclusion, the proposed equation presents two real solutions:
$$
\boxed{x_1 = 2\arctan(t_5) = -2.54602,
\qquad
x_2 = 2\arctan(t_6) = 0.595568\,}
$$
which as already written in the comments weren't trivially calculable.

Using the tangent half-angle substitution, you are left with the problem of finding the real zero of function
$$f(t)=-1+9 t^2+8 t^3-9t^4+t^6$$
Since, a least graphing, we know that the solution is small, a very first approximate is $t_0=\frac 1 3$.
Now, use a Newton-like method of order $n$ and just perform the first iteration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & t_{(n)} & \text{numerically} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  \frac{413}{1341}                   & 0.307979 &\text{Newton}  \\
 3 &  \frac{29485}{96054}                & 0.306963 &\text{Halley}  \\
 4 &  \frac{10838975}{35316213}          & 0.306912 &\text{Householder}  \\
 5 &  \frac{32542913965}{106034000589}   & 0.306910 &\text{unnamed}  \\
 6 &  \frac{775453143529}{2526645876144} & 0.306910  &\text{unnamed}  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and, for the considered range $$x=2\tan^{-1}(t_{(\infty)})-\pi$$
The largest fitting on this page is $t_{(22)}$ which is
$$\frac{18313657324135762842401341166122841569758040436209377569}{59671080794962185740857815551060426984350427588221493643}$$ which is in an absolute error of $3.162\times 10^{-33}$.

If you don't mind dealing with complex numbers, it can be derived from Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ that:
$$\sin(ax) = \frac{e^{iax} - e^{-iax}}{2i}$$
$$\cos(ax) = \frac{e^{iax} + e^{-iax}}{2}$$
So your equation becomes:
$$\left(\frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^3+\frac{e^{i3x} + e^{-i3x}}{2}-2\left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^3=0$$
Let $z = e^{ix}$.  Then:
$$\left(\frac{z + z^{-1}}{2}\right)^3+\frac{z^3 + z^{-3}}{2}-2\left(\frac{z - z^{-1}}{2i}\right)^3=0$$
$$\frac{z^3 + 3z + 3z^{-1} + z^{-3}}{8}+\frac{z^3 + z^{-3}}{2}-2\left(\frac{z^3 - 3z + 3z^{-1} - z^{-3}}{-8i}\right)=0$$
$$z^3 + 3z + 3z^{-1} + z^{-3}+4(z^3 + z^{-3})-2i(z^3 - 3z + 3z^{-1} - z^{-3})=0$$
$$z^3 + 3z + 3z^{-1} + z^{-3} + 4z^3 + 4z^{-3} - 2iz^3 + 6iz - 6iz^{-1} + 2iz^{-3} = 0$$
$$(5 - 2i)z^3 + (3 + 6i)z + (3 - 6i)z^{-1} + (5 + 2i)z^{-3} = 0$$
$$(5 - 2i)z^6 + (3 + 6i)z^4 + (3 - 6i)z^2 + (5 + 2i) = 0$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, this equation has 6 complex roots.  Finding the exact forms is...complicated, but a numerical polynomial solver gives:
$$z \approx -0.496726985220200 + 0.616944992511614 i$$
$$z \approx 0.496726985220200 - 0.616944992511614 i$$
$$z \approx -0.791774927032559 + 0.983400521742224 i$$
$$z \approx 0.791774927032559 - 0.983400521742224 i$$
$$z \approx -0.827829753380066 - 0.560979410868794 i$$
$$z \approx 0.827829753380066 + 0.560979410868794 i$$
But $z = e^{ix} \implies x = -i\log(z)$.  Of the six possible values of $z$, only two result in $x$ being a real number:
$$\boxed{x \approx -2.5460242205723356 \\ x \approx 0.5955684330174575}$$
Which are the same roots found by @πρόσεχε.  Plugging them into the original equations confirms that these are indeed solutions (to within a reasonable floating-point tolerance).
